# How to convert this jQuery code into javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use only javascript in my site. But I know only basics of javascript. Its damn easy to select elements in jQuery as it is similar to CSS selectors. But I've never done in javascript before.

This is the jQuery code which I need to convert into javascript.

```
$('ul#goto li:eq(1) a').css("color","white");
$('ul#goto li:not(:eq(1)) a').css("color","grey");
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me out on this?

HTML code:

```
<ul id="goto">
<li><a href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(0)">.</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(1)">.</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(2)">.</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(3)">.</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:sliders[0].goTo(4)">.</a></li>
</ul>

if(condition)
$('ul#goto li:eq(1) a').css("color","white");
$('ul#goto li:not(:eq(1)) a').css("color","grey");
else
$('ul#goto li:eq(2) a').css("color","white");
$('ul#goto li:not(:eq(2)) a').css("color","grey");
```

Comment: post your html code and give us the clue what to do with that

Comment: Why you need it? If it is learning purpose, just have a look at jQuery library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul#goto li:eq(1) a').css("color","white");
$('ul#goto li:not(:eq(1)) a').css("color","grey");
```

Can be replaced by:

```
document.getElementById('goto').children[1].children[0].style.color = "white";

var lis = document.getElementById('goto').children;
for( var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
    if (i==1) continue;
    lis[i].children[0].style.color = "grey";
}
```

Comment: would it be more efficient to style all as grey, then only replace the 1st with white?

Comment: @neokio Indeed it should, just a typo :P Thanks

Comment: IE8 includes comment nodes as children. http://jsbin.com/ofuwub/1/edit, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t71

Comment: @Walkerneo No, the child node there is the `<br>`, not the comment node...Edit, oops was testing in Chrome, I'll take your word for it I don't have IE :)

Comment: @nbrooks, I'm talking specifically about IE8 though.

Comment: @walkerneo Yes I suspect you're correct, however I can't test it myself. In any case, if one wanted an application to support IE8, one would need only add a second check to ensure that the node was not in fact a comment node. In this case, since we know the HTML structure it doesn't seem necessary to add it, but I think your comment serves as a useful disclaimer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
var li = document.getElementById('goto').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    if(i==1){
        li[i].children[0].style.color = 'white';
    }else{
        li[i].children[0].style.color = 'grey';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In IE, the above code worked for me. I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Anyway try the below code,

```
var li = document.getElementById('goto').getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++){
    if(i==1){
        li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'white';
    }else{
        li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].style.color = 'grey';
    }
}
```

**​Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CsLXk/3/

Comment: But sadly this doesn't work in IE! But @nbrooks code works in both!

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
 document.getElementById('mydiv').style.color = 'white';
```

Comment: I don't want to select `div`. I need to know how to select the `<a>` inside <li>

Comment: try to add id to the <a> tag